# textillate text animation repeat text line after line

Tags: jquery, animation, text, jquery-textillate

I would like to show my **two text animations** one after one using **textillate**

```
$(function(){
//   loop: true, in: {}, out: {}
//      .textillate({ minDisplayTime:10000,initialDelay: 100, loop: true, in: { effect: 'bounceInUp' },out: { delay: 3, effect: 'lightSpeedOut' }});      
$('.text1')
.textillate({ minDisplayTime:1000,initialDelay: 0,  in: { effect: 'flipInX' }, out :{  delay: 3, effect: 'lightSpeedOut'} });

$('.text2')
.textillate({ minDisplayTime:1000, loop: false, initialDelay: 7000, in: {effect: 'flipInX', shuffle: false }, out :{  delay: 10, effect: 'lightSpeedOut'} });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can animate a list of texts with the following markup:

```
<h1 class="tlt">
    <ul class="texts">
        <li>Some Title</li>   
        <li>Another Title</li>
    </ul>
</h1>
```

Is this the effect you are trying to achieve?

http://jsfiddle.net/jschr/9dKum/